# Use results from postgresql-simple in a Heist template

Tags: postgresql, haskell, heist

I am trying to combine this [Heist tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/older-but-still-interesting/compiled-heist-insight-with-no-snap-in-sight#splicing-a-list-of-composite-values) and this [postgresql-simple tutorial](http://janrain.com/blog/tutorial-building-a-sample-application-with-haskell-snap-postgresql-and-the-postgresql-simple-snaplet/).

I tried doing different variations of this.

```
splice :: C.Splice IO  
splice =  do  
  projects <- query_ "SELECT * FROM projects"  
  C.manyWithSplices C.runChildren projectSplice $ return (projects :: [Project])  
  where  
    projectSplice = do  
      "title" ## (C.pureSplice . C.textSplice $ title)  
      "description" ## (C.pureSplice . C.textSplice $ description)
```

But I kept getting this error.

```
No instance for (HasPostgres (HeistT IO IO))
  arising from a use of 'query_'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (HasPostgres (HeistT IO IO))
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  projects <- query_ "SELECT * FROM projects"
In the expression:
  do { projects <- query_ "SELECT * FROM projects";
       C.manyWithSplices C.runChildren projectSplice 
       $ return (projects :: [Project]) }
```

I don't know how to implement that instance declaration and I still don't completely grasp monads. I am not sure if I am even on the right track.

EDIT: Thanks to @mightybyte for his answer, I came up with this.

```
projectSplice = do
  "title" ## (C.pureSplice . C.textSplice $ title)
  "description" ## (C.pureSplice . C.textSplice $ description)

splice :: C.Splice (Handler App App)
splice =  C.manyWithSplices C.runChildren projectSplice $ lift $ query_ "SELECT * FROM projects"

getHeistState heistConfig = liftIO $ either (error "Heist Init failed") id <$> (runEitherT $ initHeist heistConfig)

getBuilder heistState = maybe (error "Render template failed") fst $ C.renderTemplate heistState "database"

getAllProjectsHeist :: Handler App App ()
getAllProjectsHeist = do
  let heistConfig = HeistConfig defaultInterpretedSplices defaultLoadTimeSplices ("project" ## splice) noSplices [loadTemplates "templates"]
  heistState <- getHeistState heistConfig
  builder <- getBuilder heistState
  writeBS $ toByteString builder
```

Comment: About your edit: the three last functions may be unnecessary. Just use `cRender` from module `Snap.Snaplet.Heist` to obtain the handler you want to attach to the route. Of course, you must have registered the splice during the initialization phase, using something like `addConfig` from `Snap.Snaplet.Heist`. (And if you use `heistServe` you can omit `cRender` too, as the name of the template is deduced from the path.)

Comment: You're right. That helped me simplify some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something more like this:

```
splice = do
  C.manyWithSplices C.runChildren projectSplices $ 
    lift $ query_ "SELECT * FROM projects"
  where
    projectSplices = do
      "title" ## (C.pureSplice . C.textSplice $ title)
      "description" ## (C.pureSplice . C.textSplice $ description)
```

The key here is understanding the types.  Let's annotate the above structure a little:

```
splice :: Monad n => Splice n
splice = do
  foo
  C.manyWithSplices C.runChildren projectSplices $ do
    bar
    lift baz
```

The symbol foo has the same type as `splice`, `Splice n`, which is equivalent to `HeistT n IO Blah`.  The details of `Blah` aren't important to the discussion at hand.  If you look up the type signature for `manyWithSplices`, you'll see that it returns `Splice n`, so thus far everything looks good.  You seemed to have `runChildren` and `projectSplices` correct, so let's focus on the third argument to `manyWithSplices`.  Again referring to the API docs, we see the third argument has the type `RuntimeSplice n [a]`, so that is the type `bar` must have.  But what is this `RuntimeSplice` thing.  Well, if you click on it in the API docs, you'll see that it has an instance of the MonadTrans type class.  If you click on that, you'll see that `MonadTrans` defines only one function, `lift`, which neatly enough is what we're using here.  Combining `lift`'s type signature with what we've already figured out leads us to conclude that `baz` has the type `n [a]`.

`n` is your runtime monad and `HeistT n IO` is your load time monad.  If you're working in the context of a Snap web application like the Janrain tutorial, then in your case `n` will be `Handler b b`.  You specified the type signature `Splice IO`, which won't work in the context of your question because IO is not the right monad.

Comment: Haskell always seems so obvious after the fact. This is what I needed to get me on the right track.